Tableau - Calculation involving blend data
I have a list of ideas of cost reduction that have ID, project detail and unit saving and visibility date (year and month each idea is expected to be implemented) and all models available (in the example, is only A & B). This list is in a database (SQL Server)

And I'm trying on Tableau, to calculate the saving as: Quantity of model produced within first 12 months (starting from applied date) * Unit Saving

I have a excel file with the production quantity per model/ month (photo below shows a part of it)

I'm struggling to find a solution to do the saving calculation on Tableau. I'm doing a data blending with the 2 datasource (sql server & excel file). my main problem is to get the quantity of production for the models impacted from the first 12 months after the cost reduction idea is applied
What is the best way to accomplish it on Tableau?

What have you tried so far?

IF  [YM]>=ATTR([tbl_Idea_TFT+ (TFT_Cost_Reduction)].[Start Visibility])
AND [YM]<=ATTR([tbl_Idea_TFT+ (TFT_Cost_Reduction)].[End Visibility])
THEN [Quantity Expected]
ELSE 0
END

this is the formula that I would like to apply, however, when blend is used, it is not possible to not use aggregation formula and I don't know how to do using blend data without aggregation formula

First, edit your questions to add these comment details to it, second, have you tried other ways of combining or joining your data before bringing it into tableau that way you won't get the aggregate error as tableau thinks the data is all from one source.

you can use Tableau prep to do some blending before you bring it in to tableau, might worth a shot to give it a try if you have access to it.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
